# How to implement WeakEventManager for static Event

Tags: c#, events, static, weak-references

I am trying to implement the WeakEventManager following the [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970850.aspx) by creating my own WeakEventManager.

My problem is now I have a static class `StaticPublisher` that's publishing  a static event `OnSomeStaticEvent`.

I want to subscribe to this event from another class. This is the code I have by now (simplified):

```
public static class StaticPublisher
{         
//definition of static event
    public static event EventHandler<CancelEventArgs> OnSomeStaticEvent;
    public static void OnSomeStaticEventHandler(CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        EventHandler<CancelEventArgs> handlerCopy = OnVisualDisplayBeforeRemoved;
        if (handlerCopy != null)
            handlerCopy(null, e);
    }
}
```

My WeakEventManager looks like this (following the msdn again):

```
class OnSomeStaticEventWeakEventManager : WeakEventManager
{
    private OnSomeStaticEventWeakEventManager ()
    {

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Add a handler for the given source's event.
    /// </summary>
    public static void AddHandler(StaticPublisher, EventHandler<CancelEventArgs> handler)
    {
        if (source== null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
        if (handler == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("handler");

        CurrentManager.ProtectedAddListener(source, handler);
    }
// more code follows down. but is all relative to this part
```

My problem is that I can't add any listener to this event, as I am not allowed to give in `StaticPublisher` as an argument. Is there any workaround here? I really could use some help here...

Comment: Have you considered the singleton pattern as a work around?

Comment: You don't need the `source` for a static event; you can just pass `null` instead.

Comment: Thanks I found the same in an old question. What I also had to change was changing from `AddHandler` and `RemoveHandler` to `AddListener` and `RemoveListener`. I am just not sure if I should write an answer to this or just delete this question...